# why does the show ip protocols command at each router for ospf router output not showing any Routing Information Source for all loopback 0?

Tags: ospf

```
NarS-R1(config)#router ospf 1
NarS-R1(config-router)#network 192.168.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
NarS-R1(config-router)#network 192.168.17.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
NarS-R1(config-router)#network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
NarS-R1(config-router)#end
NarS-R1#
*Mar  1 00:22:33.855: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
NarS-R1#sh run | sec ospf
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.17.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
NarS-R1#do sh ip prot
NarS-R1#conf t       
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
NarS-R1(config)#sh ip pro
NarS-R1(config)#sh ip protocols
                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

NarS-R1(config)#exit
NarS-R1#
*Mar  1 00:42:02.595: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
NarS-R1#sh ip prot
NarS-R1#sh ip protocols 
Routing Protocol is "ospf 1"
  Outgoing update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Incoming update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Router ID 1.1.1.1
  Number of areas in this router is 1. 1 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
  Maximum path: 4
  Routing for Networks:
    1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
    192.168.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
    192.168.17.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 Reference bandwidth unit is 100 mbps
  Routing Information Sources:
    Gateway         Distance      Last Update
  Distance: (default is 110)
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Routing Information Sources lists all the neighbors of this router.  Since you have none, there are no entries there.  In any case, your loopback interface would never be a neighbor, so it will never be listed.